# Create a Video Overlaying another Video

Tags: actionscript, video, flash, avi

I am trying to make a nice pretty video.

I have a AVI video from a GOPro video camera, and I hae some info I want to overlay on top of the video. Like Time, GPS, Speed, G-Force etc.

I got my raw data, and ActionScript coded it up into a Flash movie, but then worked out I have two issues.

1. Flash export to AVI is pretty crap, and basically does a screen capture.
2. The export to AVI cant be transparent or anything but spare/rectangle.

So, can anyone suggest a better way?   Should I use something other than Flash to create my speedometer, that is more friendly for overlaying on a AVI?

This is the sort of thing I am trying to create. 
youtube.com/watch?v=tT-vDtQyCbo

I have a CSV of all my raw data, and am trying to find a way to overlay it and look as professional as that link above. I can make the dials in actionscript, but then exporting to AVI with a 'screen capture' type program, they look pretty crap. But on the other hand, inporting my HD video info Flash, and it becomes pretty crap quality, and still have the export issue at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% clear on what you're trying to do.

If you mean that you want to put some info over a video using Flash, all you need to do is import your video onto the timeline on one layer and then place your information on a higher layer. If you want your video to play as a different shape, then you can simply apply a mask to the layer your video is sitting on.

If you throw in more directing information then I'll improve this answer for you :)